# Protecting JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http-headers, encode

I used jQuery Ajax to talk to `php` script, then it returns `JSON`. Then, the returned `JSON` Array Object is assigned to Javascript Variable `var myJSON = ajaxReturn;`

Normally the returned `JSON` values are not visible in Page Source or Javascript File, as it is rendered on the runtime only.

But when i open the tools like, `Firebug` and call that variable in console, like: `alert(myJSON);` the results are popping out. I do NOT want it to be as this is something secret data.

- What is the best way to prevent/protect the `JSON` at Javascript side?

Comment: You can use obfuscation tools, but ultimately if the data is sent to the browser then it will be able to be interpreted (especially if your js code needs to interpret it). So, don't send data that you don't want your user to see.

Answer (score 1):

Everything sent to the client side is public, this is the nature of front end development and you can't change it. It is impossible to hide stuff from the user if he decides to take a peek.

Comment: I dare add that it's not only "impossible to hide", but is also unnecessary to hide.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of your application is to store the `JSON` for client use, then you have no way of protecting it from being accessed. However you can do all modifications upon receiving the `JSON` and then discard it (not store it). Keep in mind that the request can still be intercepted the response can be read simply by using the networking tab of the browser developer tools.

Comment: You could still use the "Network" facility in Developer Tools to see what was sent...

Comment: I've just found this one. How about using it? http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/ Then "Obfucate" the whole JS file, as hex codes. I think it will protect more or less.

Comment: @4lvin You can use such a technique but it would in no case stop someone who really wants to retrieve and decode your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What do you do with the JSON data? In all probability, you are feeding UI controls or subsequent calls to web services. So if you would protect (i.e., encrypt) the JSON, you would still need client-side decryption, and so your JSON would still be vulnerable -- as you can just do an `alert(decryptedJSON)` too.

There is no real, safe way to protect JSON if you have to be able to decipher the data in the browser.

You can of course protect the data while it is underway over the network by encrypting it, either using HTTPS or by explicitly encrypting the data server-side and then decrypting it using client-side JavaScript. But that does not protect it from being viewed in the browser.

A better option could be to encrypt and decrypt only on the server, if that fits your scenario. So you can get encrypted JSON data from a particular web service call, then feed that data into your next web service call where it gets decrypted on the server. That way, your client-side JavaScript doesn't need to decrypt, making your data safer. But if the purpose is to populate the UI, obviously this won't fit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You have just missed the game, Once you send the data from your server then its out of your limit. Because browser like firefox can do anything, So the point is everything which renders on the client is **Public**.

Even if there were some way to block Firefox from displaying the data in firebug, its easy for anyone to write their own web client that pretends to be a web browser and then they can do whatever they want with the data.

If you really want to hide **json-data** then dont send it using ajax-json. Use diffrent terminology or server-side  programming.

Comment: I've just found this one. How about using it? http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/ Then "Obfucate" the whole JS file, as hex codes. I think it will protect more or less.

Comment: well , if u ultimately going to display data on screen then why you want to hide this data,you can Obfucate tools but the concern person anyhow manage to interpret.